# Using namespace scope

Tags: c++, namespaces

I tried the following piece of code. When i compile, i get error that there there are ambiguous instances of first_var, whereas i have introduced 
 using namespace second_space before the last cout

I guess this is because the last cout is using both the namespaces. There is no override concept for namespaces ? Is there anyway a namespace scope can be ended or it continues from the using namespace point to the end of file?

```
#include<iostream.h>
namespace first_space{
    int first_var;
}
namespace second_space{
    int first_var = 1;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    cout<<"First Namespace Variable using namespace identifier:"<<first_space::first_var<<endl;
    using namespace first_space;
    cout<<"First Namespace Variable using using identifier:"<<first_var<<endl;
    using namespace second_space;
    cout<<"Second Namespace Variable using using identifier:"<<first_var<<endl;
}
```

Edit 1:

I tried something like this below. Declared a variable with same name inside the main, assigned a value 1 to it and then used using namespace below that. But I see that, the value of first_var is printed as 1 in the last two cout.
There is no ambiguity here. So the namespace didn't have any effect? Why is it so?

```
#include<iostream.h>
namespace first_space{
    int first_var;
}
namespace second_space{
    int first_var = 1;
}
int main()
{
    int first_var =1 ;
    using namespace first_space;
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    cout<<"First Namespace Variable using namespace identifier:"<<first_space::first_var<<endl;
    cout<<"First Namespace Variable using using identifier:"<<first_var<<endl;
 //   using namespace second_space;
    cout<<"Second Namespace Variable using using identifier:"<<first_var<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
First Namespace Variable using namespace identifier:0
First Namespace Variable using using identifier:1
Second Namespace Variable using using identifier:1
```

Comment: There is no `stop using namespace` concept, as far as I'm aware...

Comment: You can use fully qualified name. What exactly are you trying to achieve? This problem usually appears when `using namespace` directive is used in header files, which should be avoided.

Comment: I was trying to understand the scope of namespaces, whether it gets overridden by the latest namespace

Comment: @CVS no, it does not. But you can enclose your using directives - and the code that relies on them - in braces. At the closing brace, those names will no longer be in scope.

Comment: @Andrew Sure.. Thats how we can make it work the way we want :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are correct, after the 2nd `using` statement, the variable `first_var` is now ambiguous because both of the two namespaces are valid and of equal precedence as far as [name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) is concerned.

The two workarounds are

a) add braces to enforce an anonymous scope ([live demo](http://cpp.sh/4nds))

```
{
using namespace first_space;
cout << "First Namespace Variable using using identifier:" << first_var << endl;
}

{
using namespace second_space;
cout << "Second Namespace Variable using using identifier:" << first_var << endl;
}
```

b) drop the `using` keyword and use the namespace scope directly

```
cout << "First Namespace Variable using using identifier:" << first_space::first_var << endl;
cout << "Second Namespace Variable using using identifier:" << second_space::first_var << endl;
```

Personally I would go with option b. One of the main reasons you add namespaces in the first place is to avoid ambiguity issues, so polluting the current scope with a bunch of `using` statements undermines that.